# kstest gives strange p-values

Tags: python, scipy, kolmogorov-smirnov

I want to check if a probability comes from a distribution specified by an empirical CDF. `kstest` gives p-values that I consider to be wrong; what's the matter?

I have written a test function to verify the p-values. I am comparing sample arrays from two identical distributions and check p-values obtained from `kstest` and `ks_2samp` functions. Since the null hypothesis is true (the distributions are identical), the p-values have to be uniformly distributed on [0,1], in other words, I must see the false discovery rate equal to the used p-value threshold.
However, this is the case only for p-values given by `ks_2samp` function.

```
from scipy import stats
from statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution import ECDF

def test():
    num_runs = 1000
    detected_kstest= 0
    detected_ks_2samp = 0

    for _ in range(num_runs):
        data1 = stats.norm.rvs(size=100, loc=1.0, scale=1.0)
        data2 = stats.norm.rvs(size=100, loc=1.0, scale=1.0)

        ecdf = ECDF(data1)
        p_threshold = 0.05

        _, p_val = stats.kstest(data2, ecdf)
        if p_val < p_threshold:
            detected_kstest += 1

        _, p_val = stats.ks_2samp(data1, data2)
        if p_val < p_threshold:
            detected_ks_2samp += 1

    print(f'FDR for p-value threshold {p_threshold} : kstest: {detected_kstest / num_runs}, ks_2samp: {detected_ks_2samp / num_runs}')
```

The output is

`FDR for p-value threshold 0.05 : kstest: 0.287, ks_2samp: 0.051`

I expect both fdr values to be near 0.05, but the value given by `kstest` is weird (too high - in other words, `kstest` often insists that the data comes from different distributions).

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

As answered below, the reason is that `kstest` doesn't handle ecdf generated by small samples well enough...
Alas, I have to generate empirical CDFs by samples that are also not very big.
For now, as a quick workaround, I use some 'hybrid' method:

```
def my_ks_test(data, ecdf, ecdf_n=None):
    n = data.size
    sorted_data = np.sort(data)
    data_cdf = np.searchsorted(sorted_data, sorted_data, side='right')/(1.0 * n)

    data_cdf_by_ecdf = ecdf(sorted_data)

    d = np.max(np.absolute(data_cdf - data_cdf_by_ecdf))

    if ecdf_n is None:
        en = np.sqrt(n)
    else:
        en = np.sqrt(n * ecdf_n/float(n + ecdf_n))

    try:
        p_val = stats.distributions.kstwobign.sf((en + 0.12 + 0.11 / en) * d)
    except:
        p_val = 1.0

    return p_val
```

So it can take as an argument the number of samples that was used in generation of ECDF. Maybe that's not exactly nathematically strict, by for now it's the best I can come up with.
When tested on data1 and data2 both of size 100, it gives

`FDR for p-value threshold 0.05 :        kstest: 0.268, ks_2samp: 0.049, my_ks_test: 0.037`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ECDF that you compute *approximates* a normal distribution, but if you test a large enough sample from an *actual* normal distribution with that ECDF, `kstest` will detect that the sample is not from the ECDF.  After all, the ECDF is not a normal distribution.

Apparently a sample size of 100 (from an actual normal distribution) is large enough that `kstest` often detects that those samples are not from the distribution associated with the ECDF that is based on `data1`.

If you increase the size of `data1` while keeping the size of `data2` fixed, you will eventually get the result that you expect.  By increasing the size of `data1`, you increase how well the ECDF approximates an actual normal distribution.

When I change the creation of `data1` to

```
        data1 = stats.norm.rvs(size=5000, loc=1.0, scale=1.0)
```

here's what I get:

```
In [121]: test()                                                                                     
FDR for p-value threshold 0.05 : kstest: 0.048, ks_2samp: 0.0465

In [122]: test()                                                                                     
FDR for p-value threshold 0.05 : kstest: 0.0515, ks_2samp: 0.0475

In [123]: test()                                                                                     
FDR for p-value threshold 0.05 : kstest: 0.0515, ks_2samp: 0.05
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, I see the point and totally agree. After all, asymptotically it works as expected, and even without increasing the size of the sample being tested (data2). But unfortunately my sample sizes are not nearly that big right now...

Answer (score 0):

So I think the reason is that ECDF function produces a step-function and doesn't do any interpolation. kstest faithfully compares a distribution to this 'strangely-looking' step-function and of course detects a difference, if no corrections are made to take into consideration that we are actually dealing with a step-function (the 'Smirnov' part of kstest; that's what two-sided ks-test does).